# Why my app not supports iphone 5 and 32 bit device anymore?

Tags: ios, iphone, 32-bit

The newest update version of my app in App Store did not support iphone 5 and 32 bit device anymore.
Here is my build setting:
[image]

The problem is the older version can be installed on iphone 5, but the newest was not. I did not change anything in build setting.

The minimum target is 9.0
[image]

*UPDATE*: change "Build Active Architecture Only" to *NO* and the problem's gone!

Comment: What version of iOS is the iPhone 5 on that you tested it with?

Comment: Are you talking about during development or an app on the App Store?

Comment: I'm running into something similar with my Enterprise distributions. Even if I add armv7 and armv7s to my valid architectures the app will not install on a 32-bit device (ie: iPod 5th gen). Likewise when I'm exporting the archive Xcode lists that the app is exporting as arm64 only.

Comment: I fixed this problem with just change the "Build Active Architecture Only" to "NO" :)